# Display featured products on category page PRESTASHOP

Tags: prestashop

I just want to show some featured products on each category page (not home page).

I thought to use features or tags. So in the back, I add to the products I want to show a "featured" tag or feature. And then in the front on each category page I display the products of that category that have that tag or feature.

What do you think is easier? and how can I achieve this? I am so lost, so I'd appreciate any guidance. 
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this:

- Create a module (obviously) to extend the product class and add a `featured` field (as a boolean, you can also use a position field if you want to manage something like that)
- Within the module it's easy to override the admin controller to add a checkbox somewhere
- On the category page, create a hook to display the featured product, or just override the `categoryController` to get them.

And voilà! It's really easy. I just give you the steps as I won't write the code for you :) but if you need more advices feel free to ask

Comment: great! thanks... thats exactly how I solved it, but know I have a problem on the" verride the categoryController" part. the issue is that i am getting the array os products and then filter them, but I get only the products on the firt page, not the products on the whole category...

Comment: OMG this is so complex for me, I am running in circles and I really can't solve it, but I am going to open a new question